# fgets being skipped/not stopping for input

Tags: c, while-loop, command-line-interface, fgets

I'm trying to use fgets in a simple while loop. fgets just simply isn't being called.

Full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LINE_BUFF 20
#define OSPID //Here is where I would put the ospid I was interested in

int readContentsOfProcessMapsFile(int target);


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

char lineprompt[LINE_BUFF];
char command1[LINE_BUFF], command2[LINE_BUFF];
int flag;


if( readContentsOfProcessMapsFile(OSPID) != 0)
{
    printf("Error reading file");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

while(1) {

    fflush(stdout);
    printf("enter name:>");
    if ( fgets(lineprompt, sizeof(lineprompt), stdin) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error using fgets\n");
        break;
    }

    sscanf(lineprompt, "%s %s", &command1, &command2);

    if (strcmp(command1, "show") == 0)
    {
        if( (strcmp(command2, "active") == 0) )
        {
            flag = 1;
        }
        else if( (strcmp(command2, "inactive") == 0) )
        {
            flag = 2;
        }
        else
        {
           flag =0;
        }
        printf("run show function on ospid file");
    }
    else if (strcmp(command1, "exit") == 0) 
    {
        printf("run exit/cleanup");
        break;
    } 
    else if (strcmp(command1, "help") == 0) 
    {
        printf("run help function");
        continue;
    } 
    else {
    printf("Nothing entered, run help function");
    continue;
  }
}
}

int readContentsOfProcessMapsFile(int target) {
  FILE *fd; // /proc/<target>/maps
  char name[128], *line = NULL, *match = NULL;
  size_t len = 0;
  char* filename = NULL;

  snprintf(name, sizeof (name), "/proc/%u/maps", target);

  if ((fd = fopen(name, "r")) == NULL) {
    printf("error");
    return (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  while (getline(&line, &len, fd) != -1) 
  {
    unsigned long start, end;
    char read, write, exec, cow;
    int offset, dev_major, dev_minor, inode;

    filename = realloca(filename, len);

    sscanf(line, "%p-%p %c%c%c%c %x %x:%x %u %[^\n]", &start, &end, &read,
            &write, &exec, &cow, &offset, &dev_major, &dev_minor, &inode, filename);
    match = strstr(filename, "/ora_");
    if (match != NULL) 
    {
        printf("##lowAddr:%p, highAddr:%p and filename:%s\n", start, end, name);
    }
  }
  free(filename);
  free(line);
  if (fclose(fd) == -1)) 
  {
    printf("Failed to close %s", fd);
    return (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I've tried adding `fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);` and `fflush(stdin);` just after the while loop, but `fgets()` is still being skipped over. I understand it's not good pratice to use `fflush(stdin)` anyway's.

When this happens `getchar()` is printing either a square or a Y with two dots above it. So am I right in thinking the reason for `fgets()` being skipped over is that it's picking up these chars? Could anyone offer a way to stop/prevent this?

Thanks for all the comments. I've narrowed it down to the above `readContentsOfProcessMapsFile` function. If I comment this out then `fgets` works as expected.

Now that I fixed my typo regarding the `close(fd)` it doesn't seem to actually be closing the file! Just found my own error there! Changed to `fclose` but see getting the same problem

Comment: @SteveSummit just extended my code to elaborate

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your `fgets` call.  Get rid of the `char b = getchar()` and the `printf("%c", b)`; those are just confusing the issue.  Don't muck aroiund with `fseek` or `fflush(stdin)`; those will just confuse the issue more.

Comment: Your problem is probably in something we can't see.  The snippet you posted is fine.

Comment: @SteveSummit, Thanks Steve, I only added it in to try and capture what was causing the issue. Any idea what could be causing it to be skipped over?

Comment: Something that we can't see, because it is not visible in the snippet you posted, is causing your problem.  Beyond that it's hard to say. But  I doubt it's being "skipped over"; I suspect some other aspect of your larger program's behavior is confusing you.

Comment: Come to think of it, I bet I know exactly what's causing your `fgets` call to be "skipped".  In the code we can't see, up before you call `fgets`, you're calling `scanf`, aren't you?

Comment: @SteveSummit, Nope, I read all the issue about using those two together

Comment: @SteveSummit,  I do call `sscanf` to extract some vars from a file though, before getting to the while loop

Comment: Okay, I'm glad you know about `scanf` and `fgets`.  But if you're hitting the "Error using fgets" case, the problem is not that `fgets` is being "skipped", the problem is that it's *failing*.  This may mean EOF, and that's somewhat confirmed by the fact that you got ÿ back from `getchar`, since ÿ is sort of equal to EOF (-1).  Are you entering control-D or control-Z?  Could `stdin` be getting closed somehow?

Comment: But, seriously, enough speculating.  You need to show us code that actually demonstrates your problem -- that is, what the pedants call an "MVCE".  Not your whole program, but a stripped-down, but complete program that both compiles and demonstrates your problem.  We can't debug what we can't see.

Comment: @SteveSummit, The first time I enter anything is when `fgets` is called. I'm not control-* anything.

Comment: `fflush( stdin )` is, as far as the C standard is concerned, *undefind behaviour*. Yes, it is well-defined on Linux; don't do it anyway.

Comment: @N3i1 No need to share your whole program; please don't put a link to the whole code base. Share a stripped-down, but complete program that both compiles and demonstrates your problem. Your current code lacks a `main` function, among other things. Read about [mcve] if you have doubts.

Comment: 18 chars of effective buf size is not s lot... Perhaps your input line is simply too long, as your code does not handle this well.

Comment: @SteveSummit, thanks for your help. Here's an MVCE

Comment: What is this: `if (close(fd == -1))` ?  The `close(FILE *)` function just requires the file descriptor as an argument, not a Boolean expression. (which will probably not be the same as the file descriptor.

Comment: `#define LINE_BUFF 20` needs to be bigger.

Comment: @ryyker, `close()` was a typo in my code. One which I've clearly overlooked. Thank you. I've tried making LINE_BUFF bigger, but still the same problem

Comment: Note that your scanf format string contains %p, but the start/end aren't pointers. You're also not freeing the buffer returned by getline() after the loop. But what I'm really curious about, is whether alloca() inside a while loop is such a good idea?

Comment: @user3121023 thank you, I’ll look to make that change

Comment: @Ove, do you mean I need to free `line` ?

Comment: @N3i1 yep, what user3121023 said.

Comment: @user3121023, I’ve made all your recommendations, thanks again. But I’m still hitting the same problem

Comment: @Ove, thanks. I wasn’t aware I had to free

Comment: @user3121023 Removed

Comment: @user3121023 sorry I don’t understand your last comment?

Comment: @DevSolar -- I have never seen `fflush(stdin)` actually work for terminal input on a Linux system. I think that the language on [some Linux man pages](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush) is misleading; [POSIX specifies that `fflush(stdin)` is only defined for _seekable_ streams](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fflush.html), and [better Linux man pages seem to concur.](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html)

Comment: @DavidBowling: I was contrasting the "works for special cases" as per Linux with the outright UB a per C99 / C11.

Comment: @DevSolar -- well, I think that you could argue that it is UB to do `scanf("%c", &ch);  fflush(stdin);` even on Linux systems, since this is only defined for seekable streams. IAC, I know that you were not recommending this; I only commented because I frequently see it mentioned (in this context of clearing the input stream after user input) that this behavior is defined in Linux. But it doesn't work in this context, and Linux man pages may be less than helpful in understanding this.

Answer (score 0):

*I'm trying to use fgets in a simple while loop. fgets just simply isn't being called.*...

When the problem you are trying to solve is is surrounded with distractions, it is likely you are spending all your efforts on the distractions and not the problem.  As shown, your code contains not only the problem(s) you describe, but a bunch of distractions.

The comments offer several suggestions to *[clean up your distractions](http://sscce.org/)*. The following is my take on no distractions:

A very simple example of a working *fgets in a loop reading stdin* example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        char temp[BUFSIZ];  //BUFSIZ defined as 512 in stdio on my system.

        while((fgets(temp,BUFSIZ,stdin)) != NULL)
                printf("%s\n",temp);

        return 0;
}
```

EOF will cause the loop to exit. (ctrl-C to stop on Windows)

When you get this to work, slowly start to include other desired functionality around it, verifying each time that the added functionality does not break the code.  As you progress, you may run into an occasional bug,  When that happens use a *[step-wise, pragmatic approach to determining the problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)*, then continue.